# RESTEasy can't find Message Body Writer for application/xml when using dynamically created class

Tags: java, xml, maven, resteasy, cglib

> Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of media type: application/xml

I am getting the above error when trying to return a response in xml of a list of dynamically created classes/dtos.

```
@GET
@Path("objects")
public Response getObjects(
        @DefaultValue("json") @QueryParam("format") String format)
{    
     GenericEntity entity;

     //I use cglib here to dynamically at runtime create a class called objectDto.
     //The class is just a POJO.

     List<Object> objectsDto = generateObjects(fields);

     entity = new GenericEntity<List<Object>>(objectsDto){};

     Response.ResponseBuilder rBuild;

    if (format.equals("xml"))
    {
        rBuild = Response.ok(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    }
    else
    {
        rBuild = Response.ok(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    return rBuild.build();
}
```

The weird thing is I can return JSON representations of this object but not XML. Also I can return XML representations of not dynamically created classes.

I have the correct dependency in my Maven project for resteasy-jaxb-provider:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: When you generate your classes with cglib do you also generate JAXB annotations for them?

Comment: I think you've hit the problem there... I need to Annotate my class with @XmlRootElement... Now to figure out how to add annotations to classes :) :) Thanks for the help bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using cglib out of the box. Since the [`XmlRootElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html) is not inherited, the subclass that is created by cglib will not longer carry this annotation. Cglib itself was written before annotations were introduced to Java and no recent update added this functionality. You can instead register an ASM visitor with the cglib enhancer which should be responsible for adding the annotation to the cglib generated class.

However, you might want to consider creating your classes using [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) which has a more modern API and supports the writing of annotations.

Comment: Yes since @Greg Whitakers comment I have also found out from other threads that this is not possible. I will look into javassist now thank you.